# MS Excel Formula - Determine count for specific text across multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to write a formula in MS Excel that will let me know if the text "Yes" is found in any of three selected columns. Below is the formula I created but it does not seem to be working. When I drag the formula to the other rows I get a "Yes" value for rows that do not have the text "Yes". The values in the columns I am searching are blank or have "Yes" text.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(AF3:AF2378,"Yes") + COUNTIF(AG3:AG2378,"Yes")
   + COUNTIF(AI3:AI2378,"Yes")=0, "1","Yes")
```

Comment: You are counting *all* of the rows in each of the 3 columns. If *any* have "Yes" your IF will result in TRUE. Is that your intent?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Yes", Array1, Array2, Array3)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that you want to check for each row alone. To do this you need to enter the formula for each row and fill down For example, at cell `AJ3`, you can write:

```
=IF(OR(AF3="Yes", AG3="Yes", AI3="Yes"), "Yes", "1")
```

Enter this formula at `AJ3` (or any other column at row 3) then copy/paste on all the column.